# Sql query to fetch posts of a user

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, relational-database

I am stuck on an SQL query. It's about fetching posts to show the user, which is shared by the people connected to him.

I have a table which shows the connection between two users. There can be 5 types of connection between two users:

- friends;
- relatives;
- colleague;
- classmate;
- acquaintance.

Any two users can be connected in more then one relationship so the table has 7 columns, which are:

```
first_user_id (int)
second_user_id (int)
friends (bool)
relative (bool)
colleague (bool)
classmate (bool)
acquaintance (bool)
```

Now, a user can share a post, which can be a thought, a photo, a video or anything else, but for now, let's consider he can share a thought. He can set privacy on his post, he can specify that only his relatives or friends will be able to access a post. Now for this reason, I have three tables.

- `Shared` – all the shared items:

  - `id (int auto_incr p_key)`;
  - `type (text)` – type of the post which is at this row, for ex. it can be `'thought'`, or `'photo'`, or `'video'`. for now, it will be `'thought'`;
  - `item_id (int)` – `id` of the item to look for in the respective table, for now, it's the `thought` table;
  - `shared_by (int)` – `id` of the user who shared this item
  - `time (datetime)` – date/time when the thought was posted
- `Thought` – this is the table for storing all the thought items, there will be separate tables for storing each type of item eg, `photo`, `video` etc.:

  - `id (int auto_incr p_key)`
  - `content (text)` – the content of the thought
- `Shared_with`:

  - `post_id (int p_key)` – the `id` value of the `shared` table will be inserted here
  - `public (bool)` – if this value is true, this is a public post and can be shared with everyone
  - `friends (bool)` – if true, this post can be shared with people who are friends with the one who posted it
  - `relative (bool)` – same as above for relatives
  - `colleague (bool)` – same for colleagues
  - `classmates(bool)` – same for classmates
  - `acquaintance (bool)` – same for acquaintance

Now the problem is, I want to fetch the top 20 posts which are either public or shared by the people connected to the user. The user should see only the post he has right to access and which are from his contact list. Can you suggest me how it can be done with single or multiple Sql queries. Also suggest some improvement in the schema.

Comment: This sounds more like "please implement my design" rather than "please help me with this technical problem I'm having".  This forum is more about the latter type of request.  I suggest posting what you've tried so far and we can help you with more specific problems.

Answer (score 0):

First some schema suggestions - change the 'connections' table to be:

```
 UserId0
 UserId1
 RelationshipId
```

Create a lookup table with

```
 RelationshipId
 Description
```

Second - change the 'shared_with' table to be:

```
 PostId
 Public
 SharedWith (this should be a bitmask for the various types of relationships for this post)
```

Another lookup table:

```
 SharedWithMask (1,2,4,etc)
 SharedWithDescription
```

Third - change TypeOf in 'shared' to be a number. Text lookups can be limiting and a pain.

In your question you don't mention what it means to be "top 20" so we'll go with 20 most recent.

```
 select itemid from shared join connections on
 shared.shared_by = connections.second_user_id join shared_with on
 shared_with.post_id = shared.id where
 connections.first_user_id = (person) and shared_with.public = true
 order by shared.datetime limit 20;
```

That's a starting point.